# Python regular expressions matching question

Tags: python, regex

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
import re

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

url = "https://foxnews.com/"
html = get_html(url)

pattern = re.compile(r'\b(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:.*?\.)\b(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)')
matches = re.findall(pattern, html)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

But it keeps matching things like this:

```
" data-src="//a57.foxnews.com/hp.foxnews.com/images/2022/05/320/180/adc987321731b78d41a3b061e67ea84c.png

href="https://www.foxnews.com/entertainment/saturday-night-live-medieval-supreme-courts-leaked-draft-opinion-abortion-roe-v-wade"
```

And so forth and so on. How can I make this get image links and filter the remaining other things out? Look around? I'm stuck here.

Comment: can you show a desired output ?

Comment: All image links from the HTML. That's what I want the output to be.

Comment: is there any contraints on how the "start" has to look like ? or really any link which ends with `png/jpg` etc.

Comment: Nope. No constraints. I want all image links regardless no matter what.

Comment: Please, check if this expression fits your needs, \/\/([\S]+(?:png|jpg|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg))
In case it do, gonna post the proper answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(?:https?://)?[^\s<>"\']*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)\b')
matches = re.findall(pattern, html)
```

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:https?://)?`  - an optional sequence of `http://` or `https://`
- `[^\s<>"\']*` - zero or more chars other than whitespace, `"`, `'`, `<` and `>`
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)` - one of the extensions listed
- `\b` - word boundary

Answer (score 0):

I have collated a set of regular expressions that are available on [patterns-finder](https://github.com/benouinirachid/patterns-finder), for finding URL I have been using the following URL regex:

```
((ftp|https?):\\/\\/(?:www\\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,}|www\\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,}|https?:\\/\\/(?:www\\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[^\\s]{2,}|www\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[^\\s]{2,})
```

You can notice the presence of ftp protocol.
With slight modifications, you can add this list of file extensions (gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp|svg|psd|bmp|tif) as it supports more common type of images.
The final regex will look like this:

```
\b((ftp|https?):\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})[^\s]*\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp|svg|psd|bmp|tif)\b
```

It will match the following:

```
https://cdn.analytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/test.jpg
http://cdn.analytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/file.jpg
http://cdn.analytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/.jpg
ftp://www.test.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/.jpg
```

It supports the case when the file name is ".jpg" or ".png", etc.
But it will not match the following:

```
http://a57.foxnews.com/images/2022/05/320/180/1e67ea84c/test.html
http://a57.foxnews.com/images/2022/05/320/180/1e67ea84c/test
http://a57.foxnews.com/images/2022/05/320/180/1e67ea84c/png
```